# Why are both Jersey endpoints being hit?

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

When I go to `.../bank/1` I see the account info as one would expect. *Great, good, fine.*

When I go to `.../bank/1/description` I see the description (*good*) but I also see the account info (***not** good*).

I am used to Spring's `GetMapping`, where things break if multiple paths match -- but even then, AFAIK, in my code, **only one** should match anyway?

## Why are both `AccountActions` being triggered?

Bank.java

```
Path("/bank")
public class Bank {

    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;

    @Context
    Request request;

    // ... Other irrelevant constructors, methods, and attributes

    @GET
    @Path("{acct}")
    public AccountAction getAccount(@PathParam("acct") String id) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "- URL: " + uriInfo.getPath());
        return new AccountAction(uriInfo, request, id, accounts);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{acct}/description")
    public AccountAction getDescription(@PathParam("acct") String id) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "- URL: " + uriInfo.getPath());
        return new AccountAction(uriInfo, request, id, accounts);
    }
}
```

AccountAction.java

```
public class AccountAction {

    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;

    @Context
    Request request;

    // ... Other irrelevant constructors, methods, and attributes

    public AccountAction(UriInfo uriInfo, Request request, String id, AccountStore accounts) {
        this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
        this.request = request;
        this.id = new Integer(id);
        this.accounts = accounts;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id:\\d+}/description")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getDescription() {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "- URL: " + uriInfo.getPath());
        Account a = accounts.find(id);
        if (a == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No such account: " + id);
        }
        return a.getDescription();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id:\\d+$}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Account getAccount() {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "- URL: " + uriInfo.getPath());
        Account a = accounts.find(id);
        if (a == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No such account: " + id);
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

**Log output:**

```
17-Jan-2020 11:54:57.526 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] edu...Bank.getDescription - URL: bank/1/description
17-Jan-2020 11:54:58.139 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] edu...AccountAction.getAccount - URL: bank/1/description
17-Jan-2020 11:54:58.140 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] edu...AccountAction.getDescription - URL: bank/1/description
```

Comment: Read the section on [sub-resource locators](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2545)

Answer (score -1):

Replace this code

> @Path("/{id:\d+$}")

by

> @Path("/{id: [0-9]*}")

Comment: That doesn't work nor does it explain why both paths would be hit.